# Check if parameter is used in url laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to check if a parameter name is included in a specific url like this: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/box?size[eq]=200](http://127.0.0.1:8000/box?size%5Beq%5D=200)

I want to retrieve the name "size[eq]" in my laravel controller but it keeps returning false.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
 
      dd($request->has("size[eq]"));
    
     }
```

Comment: Dump `$request->all()`

Comment: @Marwelln Thank you for your answer, but it just shows me an array. Is there any way to simply get the word "size[eq]" ?

Comment: in that case you should use `$request->size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an array named `size` with an index named `eq`. It isn't an actual string on the server side. Most of Laravel's functions use the "dot notation" for dealing with nested elements. So for what would be `$requestData['size']['eq']` would be:

```
$request->has('size.eq');
```

If you want to retrieve that value you would also use "dot notation":

```
$request->input('size.eq');
```